# ASP.NET MVC Connected services wants to remove my Individual Authentication to add Azure AD Authentication, no way around this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, active-directory

It is basically what the title says, is there no way to avoid removing my individual login and have both authentications work beside each other without interacting?

For example when on my domain it would use the Azure AD Authentication but when on other domains it would use simple individual authentication.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the authentication middle-ware can't work for the specific domain. However, you do can add multiple authentication middle-ware to the same web app.

For example, you can create an web app with the individual accounts. Then we can add the Azure AD authentication by following the code project [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect).

After that,  when OP click the sign button, it will list all the authentication middle-ware like below:
[image]

And then you can hide the authentication components as you wanted based on the business logic(`Login.cshtml`). I also upload a demo project which works for both Azure AD and indivual accounts, you can check it from [here](https://github.com/VitorX/webapp-aad-localaccount).